# Laravel error message against dynamic array named input

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show error message against array input name, I have an example for normal inputs

form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="">
    @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <em class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
        </em>
    @endif
</div>
```

Now I have some dynamically created fields, I need to show error message against all those inputs

```
@foreach ($names as $name)
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name[$name->id]['first']['value']" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('name' . $name->id . 'first.value'))
            <em class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ $errors->first('name' . $name->id . 'first.value') }}
            </em>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name[$name->id]['last']['value']" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('name' . $name->id . 'last.value'))
            <em class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ $errors->first('name' . $name->id . 'last.value') }}
            </em>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I have tried but it is not working, please help.

Answer (score 0):

try following,

```
@foreach ($names as $name)
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name[{{$name->id}}]['first']['value']" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('name.' . $name->id . 'first.value'))
            <em class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ $errors->first('name.' . $name->id . 'first.value') }}
            </em>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name[{{$name->id}}]['last']['value']" value="">
        @if ($errors->has('name.' . $name->id . 'last.value'))
            <em class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ $errors->first('name.' . $name->id . 'last.value') }}
            </em>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

if the above solution won't work than use the following code to print the error array and replace that key

```
`@php echo "<pre>" ; print_r($errors); @endphp`
```

We have also create a domo regarding the same . you can find it [here](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/fnt5n?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=)